# Global static variable not initialized before overloaded global new() call in C++

Tags: c++

In one project I have globally overloaded operator new/delete to make use of a private heap. The code that does this goes like (in file Allocator.cpp):

```
static HeapManager heapManager;

void * operator new (size_t size)  
{
    void * p = heapManager.AllocateFromHeap(size);
      if (p == 0) // did malloc succeed?
            throw std::bad_alloc(); // ANSI/ISO compliant behavior  
        return p;
}
```

The goal was that heapManager will be initialized when the file is loaded and then when somebody calls new(), memory will be allocated from heap. This code is packed in a dll and used by another exe.

But what we found was that somebody outside our dll code was calling new() and the heapManager was null. We solved the problem like this:

```
HeapManager* pheapManager = NULL;    

void * operator new (size_t size)  
{
    static HeapManager heapManager;
    if (pheapManager == NULL)
    {
        pheapManager = &heapManager;
    }
    void * p = pheapManager->AllocateFromHeap(size);
    if (p == 0) // did malloc succeed?
        throw std::bad_alloc(); // ANSI/ISO compliant behavior  
    return p;
}
```

But his looks ugly. Is there any better way to solve this? All I want is to make sure that the static HeapManager variable is initialized before new() is called.

Comment: When you say "heapManager was null", what exactly do you mean? It's not a pointer...

Comment: My experience is that static initialization varies from compiler to compiler. Several of the Borland/CodeGear compilers I've had to work with were terrible at it. What is your environment?

Comment: @Tobias Brick: By NULL I mean it has a value of -  heapManager {hHeap=0x00000000 }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hide it in a function:

```
HeapManager& getHeapManager()
{
    static HeapManager single;
    return single;
}

// ...

void * operator new ( ... )
{
    void* p = getHeapmanager().AllocateFromHeap( size );
    ...
```

This way it'll be created only when function is called.

Comment: Much cleaner. I tried this singleton approach, but instead of a static object, used new() .. which was causing an infinite recursion. So gave it up. But using an static object solves it.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the The Nifty Counter Trick. That's the trick used to make cout and cerr globals: http://www.petebecker.com/js/js199905.html

Comment: I might be wrong but reading the document it seems to me that my problem is a little bit different. I don't need anything to be initialized inside HeapManager's constructor, all I want is the constructor to get called. I guess overloaded new operator gets used differently than normal functions.